# Turn off Hyphenation Without Text Running Into the Margins

Tags: formatting, hyphenation

I am rewriting (and updating) my resume in LaTeX. I was dismayed because LaTeX automatically hyphenates words that need to go onto a new line when a line is too long. I found a way to turn off hyphenation (see code below), however this makes the line ragged and it runs into the margin and looks terrible. Is there a way to turn off hyphenation such that if a word is too long, the whole word is moved to the next line so a line won't run into the margin of a document?

```
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
Education \\
U. Chicago \hfill 2008-2012 \\
\begin{itemize}
\item Long bullet point describing all of my technical skills that goes for several lines
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: `\raggedright` would do this, but it would not justify the remaining lines.

Comment: Try `\usepackage{microtype}`, it reduces the number of hyphenations.

Comment: The only sensible way to have non hyphenated text is using ragged right typesetting (or writing in Vietnamese or Chinese, that have no issue with hyphenation, because it doesn't exist for these languages).

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

\begin{document}

Education \\
U. Chicago \hfill 2008-2012 

\begin{sloppypar}
\begin{itemize}
\item Loong bullet point describing all of my technical skills that goes overseverallines
\end{itemize}
\end{sloppypar}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Alex microtype package worked.

Comment: @PhilBraun: sure, that is always a good idea. But your question was about to prevent hyphenation ...